# How to increase the falling speed of the object in 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I wrote a script to the banana object which is actually was a cube see the following snapshot for my test game :

[image]

All the bananas have a collider component ,if the monkey shoot   any of those bananas by a shot then the gravity of the attached rigidbody  of the collider is enabled and the banana fall down.

my problem is that the banana falls slowly :( , So how to increase the speed of falling ?

This is the script attached to each banana :

```
#pragma strict

var other : Collider;

var collided_with: GameObject;


function Start () {

}

function Update () {



}



function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision)

{

collided_with = col.gameObject;



if(other.tag=="banana")

{


rigidbody.useGravity = true;
rigidbody.isKinematic = false;



}


if(collided_with.tag=="Down")

{

Destroy(gameObject);

}


}


function onCollisionExit(col : Collision)

{



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 options that come to mind as "easy", i'm sure there are other ways you can do this but these are the simplest i can think of right now ...

option 1: 
Set the mass property on the bannana to a higher value (in rigid body script settings).

option 2:
Call addForce on your bannana and give it the amount you want to add ...

```
bannanaGameObject.AddForce(Vector3.Down * speed);
```

Comment: You can also use "Gravity Scale" on the Rigidbody and set the scale to a higher value than 1